# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError even with small sized images in Android

Tags: java, android, performance

I am building an andorid application that has 8 buttons and I have use very small sized png images for the backgrounds. The size of all images is only `355 kb` but when I run the application it gives me error saying

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 256000012 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 119MB until OOM`

Why does it takes so much memory? Is there any better way to use less memory?
This is how I made the button in my xml. Thank You

```
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/groupmeButton"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `image1` is too large in terms of resolution (pixels wide, pixels high).

Second, you probably put `image1` in `res/drawable/`. `res/drawable/` is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`, meaning that drawables in `res/drawable/` are designed for `mdpi` screens. If you run your app on a higher-density screen, Android will upscale the image to adapt to the higher density. Instead of putting drawables like PNGs and JPEGs in `res/drawable/`, either:

- Have different versions of the same image for different densities. The Image Asset wizard in Android Studio can set this up for you.
- Or, put the image in `res/drawable-anydpi/`, to tell Android not to upscale or downscale the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can you vector Drawable now as Android is supporting Vectors as well.
To support vector below API level 21 you can follow below official link.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

Probably that can help you to avoid huge memory for images.